# Find and update a record across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to find a record (that will be present across one of the 10 similarly structured tables) based on ID number column and update column values for it from a temporary table. ID number for each record will be unique across those 10 tables.

Please suggest the best and performance efficient approach. I was thinking of below code so far for each of those 10 tables -

```
update t
set t.column1 = tt.value
from #temptable tt
inner join table1 t on t.id = tt.id
```

Comment: Please specify **only one** DBMS.

Comment: Why do you have 10 similarly structured tables?

Comment: This might be a rare instance where a VIEW is actually useful.

Comment: If you know the tables it's going to be in, why not run an `UPDATE` against each with a `WHERE`? You know your design, and what tables, the data is going to be in. (Though this does sound possibly like a design flaw.)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your sample query and question do not seem related.

Comment: 10 table names. You have written the query in the proper form. Copy, paste, replace. Why make this so complicated? Why spend so much time and effort for something so trivial?